# Include file from outside the project folder in pyproject.toml using hatch build backend

Tags: python, build, hatch

Given the following folder structure:

```
-folder1
    -folder2
        -folder3
            -a.py
        -pyproject.toml
    -xyz.txt
```

And pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "folder2"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "asd"

[tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel.force-include]
"../xyz.txt" = "folder3/xyz.txt"
```

Enter `folder2` and run `python -m build`. According to https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/#forced-inclusion ,
it should generate a wheel file that contains `folder2` with 2 files in it: `a.py` and `xyz.txt`, since

`The force-include option allows you to select specific files or directories from anywhere on the file system that should be included and map them to the desired relative distribution path.`. However, `xyz.txt` is not included. If I specify an absolute path to `xyz.txt` it works. However, relative path should also work according to the example shown at the forced-inclusion section: `"../artifacts" = "pkg"`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [python.org packaging structure](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-the-package-files) will avoid these problems.

- See my [pyproject.toml](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu/blob/main/pyproject.toml) for how I package an `examples` directory which exists at the same level as the `src` directory:

```
├── dist
├── examples
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
└── tests
```

- in particular:

```
[tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel.force-include]
"examples" = "distrobuilder_menu/examples"

[project]
name = "distrobuilder_menu"
```

- Using this project layout with your `pyproject.toml` in the top level removes the need for relative includes.
- Ensure your include path leads with `{name}/dir` so you package things within your module & not under `site-packages`.